# Where does API key go in Google Cloud Vision API?

Tags: python, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Want to use Google's Cloud Vision API for OCR. Using the python sample code [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text#vision-text-detection-python) we have:

```
def detect_text(path):
"""Detects text in the file."""
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations
print('Texts:')

for text in texts:
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

    vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

    print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
```

Where do I put my API key? I (obviously) can't authenticate without it.

Comment: I have the same problem. There is documentation how to use an API key with the REST APIs directly, but not how to use it with the provided clients.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started),

> If you plan to use a service account with client library code, you need to set an environment variable.
>
> Provide the credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Replace [PATH] with the location of the JSON file you downloaded in the previous step.
>
> For example:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/service-account-file.json"
```

So it looks like you should create a service account, download a credentials file, and set up an environmental variable to point to it.

Comment: @Adam4HD You'll need a windows-specific way of setting an environmental value

Comment: Is there any way of specifying API_KEY without setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable?

Comment: @RovshanMusayev, take a look at https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication and see if any of those strategies work for you. I'm not sure how the state of things has changed since I wrote this answer, but its possible that its now incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways through which you can authenticate

1. Exporting the credential file as an environment variable. Here is a sample code:

```
from google.cloud import vision

def get_text_from_image(image_file):
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "./creds/xxxx-xxxxx.json"
        try:
            # process_image is a method to convert numpy array to bytestream
            # (not of interest in this context hence not including it here)
            byte_img = process_image_to_bytes(image_file)
            client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
            image = vision.Image(content=byte_img)
            response = client.text_detection(image=image)
            texts = response.text_annotations
            return texts
        except BaseException as e:
            print(str(e))
```

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] is doing the work here

2. Using oauth2

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def get_text_from_image(image_file):
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("./creds/xxx-xxxxx.json")
        try:
            # process_image is a method to convert numpy array to bytestream
            # (not of interest in this context hence not including it here)
            byte_img = process_image_to_bytes(image_file)
            client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=creds)
            image = vision.Image(content=byte_img)
            response = client.text_detection(image=image)
            texts = response.text_annotations
            return texts
        except BaseException as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Here we are using the google-auth library to create a credential file from the JSON credential file and passing that object to ImageAnnotatorClient for authentication.

Hope these sample snippets helped you